# Find if value exists in column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I extend my function to check if the new email already exists in column F?

```
function emailUpdate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var emailRow = ss.getRange("F2:F").getValues(); 
  var emailRowNum = emailRow.filter(String).length + 1;

  var emailNew = ss.getRange("F"+emailRowNum).getValues();
  return emailNew;}
```

So I have a googlesheet with emails saved in column F. I am trying to compare the last row value (`emailNew`) with all previous values in column F but I'm unsure how to do that ...

Comment: What is "String" in `var emailRowNum = emailRow.filter(String).length + 1;`

Comment: Can't really tell you but it comes from this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17637159/revisions ... gets the value of the last row in a column ...

Comment: There is not enough information here.  Is an email value being passed to the function?  For example:  `emailUpdate( the_Email_To_Look_For ) {`

Comment: No ... I am not trying to pass anything in the function. I have a sheet with emails saved in column F. I am trying to check if the last row value in column F is in any of the previous rows. (Was going to use the 'on change from spreadsheet' trigger as the sheet us autoUpdated from another script).

Comment: You need to get the last row:  `var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();`  Then use the last row number to get the value in the last row.  `var email_InLastRow = ss.getRange(lastRow,6).getValue();`

Comment: I've already done that ... `emailNew` is the value of the last row in column F. My question is how to compare that value with all previous values in column F?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the last value in a range with all of the previous values.

```
function comparelastvalue()
 {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
   var lastRow=sh.getLastRow();
   var rg=sh.getRange(2, 6, lastRow, 1);
   var vA=rg.getValues();
   var theseRowsEqualTheValueInTheLastRowA=[];
   for(var i=0;i<lastRow-2;i++)
   {
     if(vA[i][0]==vA[lastRow-1][0])
     {
       theseRowsEqualTheValueInTheLastRowA.push(i+2);
     }
   }
 }
```