# Check if value exists before copy-paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can someone help please as I am new to Google Scripts.

I have this simple code that copies values from one sheet to another

```
function copyrevision() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fallas Tecnicas");

  //DATE
  var source = ss.getRange ("D4");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

  //REPORT NUMBER
  var source2 = ss.getRange ("C4");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(),2);
  source2.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});

  //OBSERVACION
  var source6 = ss.getRange ("E49");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(),6);
  source6.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

I need this operation to be done only if the report number value does not exist in the column 2 of destination sheet.

How can it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find if value exists in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059196/find-if-value-exists-in-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commonly use two different functions to compare a Google Sheet column against a single value.

```
function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

Read in the column, which will be presented as a 2-d array, so I flatten it to make it easier to compare with a single value.

```
  function flatten(arrayOfArrays){
    return [].concat.apply([], arrayOfArrays);
  }
```

First read in the report numbers in that column

```
var reportNumbers = ss.getRange("C:C").getValues();
```

Then I read in the value I'm comparing against the flattened array.

```
var valueToCompare = ss.getRange("C4").getValue();
    if (isInArray(valueToCompare, flatten(reportNumbers)) == true){
         // value is in array
       };
```

I compare the two elements if the value is in the array, then I get true, if not then false.

Sources for these functions
https://gist.github.com/MauricioMoraes/225afcc9dd72acf1511f

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isBlank()` :

```
if (destRange.isBlank()) source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
```

Comment: no, I mean I need the code to check the column 2 values (report numbers) and if the column does not have yet the new report number - execute all the function.